# using inputs variables into csv file

Tags: python, csv

iam trying to save user input under the csvcolumns as shown below, but each input is being saved in its own row. 
Example: if you input John under the name variable, its  being saved as j
                                                                        o
                                                                        h
                                                                        n
below is the code.

```
import time
import csv
csvcolumns= [ "NAME", "CAR MAKE", "YEAR OF MANUFACTURE", "IDENTIFICATION     NUMBER", "DATE"]
Name= input("Enter your name: ")
Car_make= input("Enter your car make e.g Toyota probox: ")
YOM= input("Enter the car YOM: ")
ID= input("Enter your identification number details: ")
todays_date= time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
with open('E:\doo.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
  writer=csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
  writer.writerow(csvcolumns)
  writer.writerows(zip(Name, Car_make,YOM,ID,todays_date))


print("writing completed")
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem with python interpreting your String `Name` as an iterable sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You're lost somewhere in complex things.

If all this data is single row, write it with

```
writer.writerow([Name, Car_make, YOM, ID, todays_date])
```